# Postgres latency issues during memory compaction on EC2 (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: postgresql, linux, memory, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

We've recently upgraded our EC2 instance that hosts our Postgres database to an i2.8xlarge with 244GB of memory (this is to utilise the large amounts of ephemeral storage it comes with). Since upgrading, we've been having some issues with latency in Postgres that appear to be due to memory compaction that's occurring in the Linux kernel.

We're using PostgreSQL 9.3 on a recent Ubuntu 14.04 kernel running the following (hopefully relevant subset of) config:

```
max_connections = 1000
effective_cache_size = '220GB'
shared_buffers = '24GB'
work_mem = '25MB'
maintenance_work_mem = '1024MB'
fsync = off
full_page_writes = on
synchronous_commit = off
```

We have transparent huge pages completely disabled on this server (`/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` and `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag` are both set to never and `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/khugepaged/defrag` is set to `0`) and we're fairly sure that we're not seeing any issues as a result of THP because the `thp_*` stats and `nr_anon_transparent_hugepages` stat in `/proc/vmstat` never increment.

Our issue is that we see constant memory compaction (failure and success) events in `/proc/vmstat` (all the stats under `compact_*` incrementing frequently) and some of these cause pretty severe stalls that get worse over time (presumably as memory fragmentation gets worse) and impact on our application. We're tracking the stats from `/sys/kernel/debug/extfrag/unusable_index` and often see a flurry of movement between the different page orders when we see stall-causing events.

We're wondering whether this is just some combination of Postgres version, Linux kernel version and having to deal with a large amount of memory (as obviously most of the memory usage is file cache, so Linux might be doing things with that that Postgres isn't happy about), but haven't been able to come up with anything other than assuming a more recent version of Postgres (9.4 or 9.5) might avoid the issue altogether for some reason.

```
$ uname -a
Linux db-04 3.13.0-91-generic #138-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 17:00:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ dpkg -l postgresql-9.3
postgresql-9.3     9.3.13-1.pgdg14.04+1
```

We also tried reducing the `effective_cache_size` on the instance to 160GB to see if we could reduce memory pressure but that didn't change much (and mostly seemed to make the stalling worse).

Just wondering if memory stalls on Postgres is something that's been raised before or that people have experience with?

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but we had serious problems with the 3.13 kernel.   So, depending on the release we use, we opt for either 3.11 or 3.16.

Comment: @dezso Did that completely solve your problems then? We would've used a newer kernel just by virtue of using a newer AMI around the same time, so we think this could be an issue before, but we would've always been on 3.13 (just older), but not sure if it's something that's been introduced that would only be fixed in something like 3.16.

Comment: We've seen this outside of AWS (therefore we do not even have EC2 instances with 3.13), and I don't remember exactly what the issue was, but something related to connections and kernel dumps.  And yes, 3.16 solved our issues (and haven't seen any ever since).  Unfortunately, we don't yet have anything big on EC2, so cannot tell much about using this kernel there.

Comment: @dezso Thanks for the guidance, we're trying Trusty but with the Xenial (4.4) kernel at the moment and it looks a lot more positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dezso mentioned in the question comments, this did seem to be an issue with (possibly more recent versions of the) 3.13 kernel in Ubuntu Trusty - we switched to the Xenial HWE 4.4 kernel in Trusty and the problem seems to have gone away and compaction stalls are now very small and don't interfere.